# CloudSearch wildcard query not working with 2013 API after migration from 2011 API

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudsearch

I've recently upgraded a CloudSearch instance from the 2011 to the 2013 API. Both instances have a field called `sid`, which is a text field containing a two-letter code followed by some digits e.g. LC12345. With the 2011 API, if I run a search like this:

```
q=12345*&return-fields=sid,name,desc
```

...I get back 1 result, which is great. But the sid of the result is `LC12345` and that's the way it was indexed. The number 12345 **does not** appear anywhere else in any of the resulting document fields. I don't understand why it works. I can only assume that this type of query is looking for any terms in any fields that even *contain* the number 12345.

The reason I'm asking is because this functionality is now broken when I query using the 2013 API. I need to use the structured query parser, but even a comparable wildcard query using the simple parser is not working e.g.

```
q.parser=simple&q=12345*&return=sid,name,desc
```

...returns nothing, although the document is definitely there i.e. if I query for `LC12345*` it finds the document.

If I could figure out how to get the simple query working like it was before, that would at least get me started on how to do the same with the structured syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Why it's not working

CloudSearch v1 (2011) had a different way of tokenizing mixed alpha+numeric strings. Here's the logic as described in the archived [docs](http://awsdocs.s3.amazonaws.com/cloudsearch/2011-02-01/cloudsearch-dg-2011-02-01.pdf) (emphasis mine).

> If a string contains both alphabetic and numeric characters and is at
>   least three and no more than nine characters long, the alphabetic and
>   numeric portions of the string are treated as separate tokens. **For
>   example, the string DOC298 is tokenized into two terms: doc 298**

CloudSearch v2 (2013) [text processing](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloudsearch/latest/developerguide/text-processing.html) follows [Unicode Text Segmentation](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr29/), which does not specify that behavior:

> Do not break within sequences of digits, or digits adjacent to letters (“3a”, or “A3”).

### Solution

You should just be able to search `*12345` to get back results with any prefix. There may be some edge cases like getting back results you don't want (things with more preceding digits like AB99912345); I don't know enough about your data to say whether those are real concerns.

Another option would would be to index the numeric prefix separately from the alphabetical suffix but that's additional work that may be unnecessary.

Comment: Wow, I suppose the dev team must have had good reason to suspect that tokenization like that is a common enough use case. The * before the digits actually still isn't working for me with the 2013 API. Regardless, I think your suggestion about re-indexing with separate fields is the way to go. I'm only interested in searching the numeric part of the field, and the alphabetic chars (or what they represent) are essentially captured in another field anyway. So, I'd rather not add additional complexity to my search queries unnecessarily. Thanks dude, as always!

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you are using Cloudsearch in English, so maybe this isn't your specific problem, but also watch out for Stopwords in your search queries:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloudsearch/latest/developerguide/configuring-analysis-schemes.html#stopwords

In your example, the word "jo" is a stop word in Danish and another languages, and of course, supported languages, have a dictionary of stop words that has very common ones. If you don't specify a language in your text field, it will be English. You can see them here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloudsearch/latest/developerguide/text-processing.html#text-processing-settings